# How to pick the smallest of the consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the data in a table sorted by Date desc.

[image]

If there are multiple consecutive rows with identical description, I'd like to take the just one with the oldest date.  For instance, rows 2 and 3 are *Unknown*, I want to keep just the one on *9/12/2014*.

I've been trying it with a CTE combined with ROW_NUMBER(), but I am unable to limit it to rows with consecutive identical description.

```
;WITH removeConsecutiveRows AS (
  SELECT ph.Description,
       ph.Price,
       ph.Date,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY ph.Description
          ORDER BY ph.Date
       ) AS rowNum 
  FROM #PriceHistory ph (NOLOCK)
)
SELECT s.Description,
       s.Price,
       s.Date,
       s.rowNum
FROM removeConsecutiveRows s
WHERE s.rowNum = 1
ORDER BY s.Date DESC
```

So at the end, it should look like this:

[image]

I should note that this is SQL Server 2008.

Comment: If you search for "gaps and islands", you'll get a bunch of possible solutions for getting the consecutive groups (imho, the easiest method to do this is using a difference in row numbers like `grp = row_number() over (order by date) - row_number() over (partition by description order by date)`). I guess you'd also need to get the first row of each island as well (so like `rn = row_number() over (partition by description, grp order by date)` and `where rn = 1`).

Comment: Instead of Image is it possible to share the data in tabular format ?

Comment: @Avi Sure.  http://rgelb.github.io/public/misc/gaps.csv

Comment: @Avi Or with slightly different data types...  an insert into a temp table.  https://pastebin.com/mt63uZ5H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a "gaps-and-island" problem with a "top-1-per-group" on top, after the groups/islands are detected.

Here is one way to do it.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( Descr varchar(50), [Price] int, dt date )
INSERT INTO #temptable
VALUES
( 'Active', 799900, N'2019-02-27T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Unknown', 629900, N'2014-09-24T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Unknown', 629900, N'2014-09-12T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Sold', 625900, N'2014-09-08T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Unknown', 629900, N'2014-08-10T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-07-27T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Pending', 629900, N'2014-07-25T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Pending', 629900, N'2014-07-24T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Unknown', 629900, N'2014-07-20T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-07-16T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-07-15T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Taking Backup Offers', 629900, N'2014-07-11T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-06-28T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-06-27T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Taking Backup Offers', 629900, N'2014-06-27T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-06-23T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-06-11T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Active', 629900, N'2014-06-10T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Sold', 570000, N'2010-01-22T00:00:00' ), 
( 'Sold', 288000, N'2000-09-01T00:00:00' );
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        * 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Descr ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn2
    FROM #temptable
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,rn1 - rn2 AS Groups
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Descr, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY dt) AS rn
    FROM CTE_RN
)
SELECT Descr, Price, dt
FROM CTE_Groups
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

**Result**

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+
|        Descr         | Price  |     dt     |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| Active               | 799900 | 2019-02-27 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-12 |
| Sold                 | 625900 | 2014-09-08 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-08-10 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-27 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-24 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-07-20 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-15 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-07-11 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-10 |
| Sold                 | 288000 | 2000-09-01 |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
```

Note, that since there are two rows with the same date `2014-06-27`, the server may return them like you showed in your expected result, or it can return them as shown here. Most likely you have an `ID` column, so use it to resolve the sorting.

---

To understand how it works run the intermediate query and examine its result (columns `rn1, rn2, Groups, rn`).

```
WITH
CTE_RN
AS
(
    SELECT
        * 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn1
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Descr ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rn2
    FROM #temptable
)
,CTE_Groups
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        ,rn1 - rn2 AS Groups
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Descr, rn1 - rn2 ORDER BY dt) AS rn
    FROM CTE_RN
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_Groups
ORDER BY dt DESC;
```

**Result**

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
|        Descr         | Price  |     dt     | rn1 | rn2 | Groups | rn |
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
| Active               | 799900 | 2019-02-27 |   1 |   1 |      0 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-24 |   2 |   1 |      1 |  2 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-12 |   3 |   2 |      1 |  1 |
| Sold                 | 625900 | 2014-09-08 |   4 |   1 |      3 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-08-10 |   5 |   3 |      2 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-27 |   6 |   2 |      4 |  1 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-25 |   7 |   1 |      6 |  2 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-24 |   8 |   2 |      6 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-07-20 |   9 |   4 |      5 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-16 |  10 |   3 |      7 |  2 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-15 |  11 |   4 |      7 |  1 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-07-11 |  12 |   1 |     11 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-28 |  13 |   5 |      8 |  2 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |  14 |   6 |      8 |  1 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |  15 |   2 |     13 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-23 |  16 |   7 |      9 |  3 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-11 |  17 |   8 |      9 |  2 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-10 |  18 |   9 |      9 |  1 |
| Sold                 | 570000 | 2010-01-22 |  19 |   2 |     17 |  2 |
| Sold                 | 288000 | 2000-09-01 |  20 |   3 |     17 |  1 |
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
```

---

### A word of caution

Adding `ORDER BY dt DESC, rn1 ASC` to the main query doesn't guarantee that it will produce the result you expect. `rn1` with values 14 and 15 may be swapped, because their date (`2014-06-27`) is the same. If the dates are not unique you need an extra unique column to make the sorting stable and predictable. There is no such column in your sample data, but usually tables have unique primary key, so you should use it.

So, for your sample data it is perfectly normal for the query to result this result:

**Intermediate**

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
|        Descr         | Price  |     dt     | rn1 | rn2 | Groups | rn |
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
| Active               | 799900 | 2019-02-27 |   1 |   1 |      0 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-24 |   2 |   1 |      1 |  2 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-12 |   3 |   2 |      1 |  1 |
| Sold                 | 625900 | 2014-09-08 |   4 |   1 |      3 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-08-10 |   5 |   3 |      2 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-27 |   6 |   2 |      4 |  1 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-25 |   7 |   1 |      6 |  2 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-24 |   8 |   2 |      6 |  1 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-07-20 |   9 |   4 |      5 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-16 |  10 |   3 |      7 |  2 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-15 |  11 |   4 |      7 |  1 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-07-11 |  12 |   1 |     11 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-28 |  13 |   5 |      8 |  1 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |  14 |   2 |     12 |  1 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |  15 |   6 |      9 |  4 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-23 |  16 |   7 |      9 |  3 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-11 |  17 |   8 |      9 |  2 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-10 |  18 |   9 |      9 |  1 |
| Sold                 | 570000 | 2010-01-22 |  19 |   2 |     17 |  2 |
| Sold                 | 288000 | 2000-09-01 |  20 |   3 |     17 |  1 |
+----------------------+--------+------------+-----+-----+--------+----+
```

**Final**

```
+----------------------+--------+------------+
|        Descr         | Price  |     dt     |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
| Active               | 799900 | 2019-02-27 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-09-12 |
| Sold                 | 625900 | 2014-09-08 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-08-10 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-27 |
| Pending              | 629900 | 2014-07-24 |
| Unknown              | 629900 | 2014-07-20 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-07-15 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-07-11 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-28 |
| Taking Backup Offers | 629900 | 2014-06-27 |
| Active               | 629900 | 2014-06-10 |
| Sold                 | 288000 | 2000-09-01 |
+----------------------+--------+------------+
```

As you can see, this result is different from the first result, because there are two rows with the same date and engine is free to put them in any order.

In this result there is `Active` with a different date `2014-06-28`, because `Active` with `2014-06-27` happened to be put below `Taking Backup Offers 2014-06-27`.

Comment: In the intermediate result, there is an `Active` entry between `Taking Backup Offers`.  But int he final result, `Active` moves down under `Taking Backup Offers`, creating yet more islands.  How would I fix that?

Comment: Ah, figured it out.  `ORDER BY dt DESC, rn1 ASC`;

Comment: @AngryHacker, `ORDER BY dt DESC, rn1 ASC` doesn't guarantee that it will produce the expected result. `rn1` with values 14 and 15 may be swapped, because their date (`2014-06-27`) is the same. If the dates are not unique you need an extra unique column to make the sorting stable and predictable. There is no such column in your sample data, but usually tables have unique primary key, so you should use it. See updated answer for details